# Image Rollover jQuery method behaving strangely

Tags: jquery

I built a jQuery function for image rollover i.e. when I hover over particular images they should magnify. But the catch is those images are of two types, sometimes they are with green border and sometimes with red border. When they have a red border then image name ends with **"RB"**. Now the problem is irrespective of the image contains RB or not it is getting magnified. I have used a boolean as a decider parameter, its name is **"pos"**. When I print it, correct value get displayed, but inside the code logic it is all wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var preLoadImages=['../icons/alfresco64.png','../icons/RSS64.jpg',
                            '../icons/google_calendar64.png','../icons/connections64.png',
                            '../icons/linkedin64.png','../icons/salesforce64.png',
                            '../icons/sharepoint_2010_64.png'];

        var imgs=[];
        for(var i=0;i<preLoadImages.length;i++){
            imgs[i]=new Image();
            imgs[i].src=preLoadImages[i];
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){


            $('#slider img').mouseover(function(){
                var j;
                var imgFile=$(this).attr('src');
                var imgFileID=$(this).attr('id');

                if(imgFileID=="Alfresco"){
                    j=0;
                }
                if(imgFileID=="GoogleCalendar"){
                    j=2;
                }
                if(imgFileID=="Linkedin"){
                    j=4;
                }
                if(imgFileID=="Rss"){
                    j=1;
                }
                if(imgFileID=="Salesforce"){
                    j=5;
                }
                if(imgFileID=="Sharepoint"){
                    j=6;
                }
                if(imgFileID=="Connections"){
                    j=3;
                }
                if((j>=0)&&(j<=6)){
                var pos=/RB.png$/.test(imgFile);

                if(pos){
                    return false;
   } if(!pos){
                $(this).hover(
                function(){
                    $(this).attr('src',imgs[j].src);
        },
                function(){
                    $(this).attr('src',imgFile);
                }
       );
       }
                } 
            });
        });
    </script>
```

According to me when image src contains RB, the method should return false. But it always magnifies the image on hover.
Please help I am a newbie to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to do recognition on name, after 2-3 weeks you will forget about this little thing. Put a html5 like attribute to your images and use it for making difference.

And if in only hover effect you can try to do it with clean css and skip the js. If you use css look how to make a 'sprite' and use it to boot loading speed.

Comment: I use CSS, but how is a sprite relevant to my situation. I used CSS for same thing, but I want to learn the jquery way of doing it, which is actually working. But my problem is why it is working always even when it is not supposed to work. i.e. when pos variable is true.

Comment: i can't tell only by this code, if you send the whole project i will try to debug it. (skype = "aleksandrenko")

Comment: Thanks but it is a company project so can't share more than snippets. I turned back to JavaScript and CSS way, and solved my problem. But I wanted to solve it via jQuery.

Comment: If it is static it's better done with just css. About the sprite ... make a block element with defined size, set the sprite as background and set the position as needed, on hover just change the bachground position, this way you have just 1 request and all images are preloaded ;)

Comment: Thanks the sprite way seems exciting, will try that for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a jsFiddle I can help but at first glance this may be an issue:

```
if (pos) {
   return false;
} 

if (!pos) { 
     ... 
}
```

Change it to:

```
if (pos) {
   return false;
} else { 
     ... 
}
```